# Redis intersection - analog of Where

Tags: data-structures, redis, redis-cluster

I have following struct

```
user_id: [
{item_id:delivered_at},
{item_id:delivered_at},
{item_id:delivered_at}
]
```

What I need to do: I have array of item_id's for user_id as argument and I need to check, if they were delivered or not.
I see two approaches here:

1. I store just *key:string*, in this case key will be ***user_id:item_id*** and value ***delivered_at***. So when I have array of item_id's, then I can query consistently all item_id's (and one network request) to return *delivered_at* for each item_id if it exists.
2. Second approach is to store for each user_id a zset, key will be *user_id*, and zset will be score: *delivered_at* and value:*item_id*.

Why I don't like the first approach - I cannot easily get all items for provided user, which would be very handful and next task will be exactly this.

What would be perfect-if I could intersect incomming set of item_id's with those in zset.
As far as I understood - I can intersect sets, but only 2 sets in redis, so in my case I need to create new temp set, and after that intersect it with one in zset.
There is an alternative way for 2nd approach- I can just get all items for provided user from zset and after that intersect sets in application, however I don't like this way because there can be thousands of deliveries for user, and it isn't great idea to transfer couple of MB of data for checking 2 or 3 deliveries.
Is there any option to intersect INCOMING set with already present in Redis?
Is there a better approach to storing data for this specific case? I've read some articles, including secondary indexes in redis blog.

Comment: It looks that I can use  ZSCORE key member and store delivered_at as score and item_id as member. Then when I call ZSCORE key will be user_id, and score delivered_at. If member exists, than redis will return score, else it will return nil. That means that I can do this in a loop and it will return all delivered_at if item has been delivered. However, disadvantage of this method is that you can not store additional data in value of zset.